# cannot unpack non-iterable ModelBase object in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

i want to view a single in item list with the help of its id but unable to achieve that i am using cbv it is showing me above mention error i am creating a ecommerce website where i want to load only that item detail which he clicking from all the items but unable to achieve showing me above error

my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):

    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='our_items')
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    can_buy = models.ForeignKey(For, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='for_wearing')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    contain_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='Bagh')
    first = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    second = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    third = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fourth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fifth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    item_vedio = models.FileField(upload_to='item_vedio', blank=True)
    offered_price = models.FloatField(blank=False,)
    actual_price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    about = models.TextField(blank=False, default="about" )
    offer = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my views.py

```
class Product_detail(View):
    def get(self, request, products_id):
        item = Item.objects.get(Item, pk=products_id)
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        print(item)
        return render (request, 'products.html',{"item_list" : item, 'category_list': category_list })
```

my urls.py

```
path('<int:products_id>/details',Product_detail.as_view(),name='detail')
```

my href tag

```
<a href="{% url 'products:detail' products.id %}">
```

any suggestion will be appreciated thank you for your time

the view of html where all item are showing

```
class Product(View):
    def get(self, request, subcategory_id):
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategories, pk=subcategory_id)
        products = subcategory.products.all()
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        print(products)
        return render (request, 'products.html',{"subcategory_list" : products, 'category_list': category_list })
```

i guess you need that

adding products.html

```
<section class="col-10">
          {% for products in subcategory_list %}
          <a class="products" href="{% url 'products:detail' products_id %}">
          <div class="card col-4" style="width: 18rem; height:400px">
              <img class="img" src="{{ products.first.url }}" alt="" height="300px" width="100%" onmouseover="this.src='{{ products.second.url }}'"
              onmouseout="this.src='{{ products.first.url }}'" >
              <div class="detail">
              <h4 class="price">{{ products.offered_price|currency}}</h4>
              <h5>{{products.name}} <br> <span>{{ products.brand_name}}</span> </h5>
              <p class="rate">Rate: 4.5<i class="fas fa-star"></i></p>
              <h6>Size:<span> {{products.contain_size}}</span> </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
            {% endfor %} 
          </div>  
        </section>
```

my poducts url

```
path('<int:subcategory_id>/products/',Product.as_view(),name='product'),
```

adding traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/1/details

Django Version: 3.2.5
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'accounts',
 'products']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\coolbuy\products\views.py", line 29, in get
    item = Item.objects.get(Item, pk=item_id)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 424, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1393, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\mithlesh\Desktop\coolbuy 2.0\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1283, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: TypeError at /1/details
Exception Value: cannot unpack non-iterable ModelBase object
```

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback? Also `"item_list" : item`, item here is just one instance, are you using this as a list in your template?

Comment: @bdbd i just added actually i linked my subcategory with item so when i click on any specific subacategory it products.html will open the list of item which is related to that subcategory so i want to achieve whe any one click on any item of that subcategory then products.detail openup and an only that item related content show up

Comment: @bdbd sorry that was typo using it as list i want only that item detail on that page not list

Comment: Can you add the whole traceback

Comment: @bdbd added the traceback

Comment: The traceback tells you exactly the problem on this line: `Item.objects.get(Item, pk=item_id)`. Try to fix that first

Comment: i fixed that but now its not rendering the detail of that item

Comment: but it is printing the item name in terminal

Comment: i made it worked thank you by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your URLs href

You can try like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'products:detail' products_id=products.id %}">
```

Comment: added my products view where all the items are showing